# C Determine the "un-flattened" location of the "flattened" ith element in an n-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, metaprogramming

I have the following (incomplete) function:

```
/* Populates char* name with the named location of the ith (flat) element
 * of an array with ndim dimensions where the length of each dimension 
 * is already stored in the int* dim.
 * 
 * name: a pointer to where the name should be populated
 * n: the base name of the array
 * dim: an int[] containing the length of each dimension
 * ndim: length of the dim array
 * i: name of the iteration variable being used
 **/
void populateName(char *name, const char *n, int *dim, int ndim, const char *i) {
  strcpy(name, n);
  char *loc = (char*)(name + strlen(n));
  char *curr;
  for (int k = 0; k < ndim; k++) {
    ...
    sprintf(loc, "[%s]", curr);
    loc += strlen(loc);
  }
}
```

What should go in the "..." in the for loop? For example, calling populateName() with:

```
int dim[2] = {3, 4};
char name[1024];
populateName(name, "x", dim, 2, "i");
```

should result in something like:

```
name = "x[i / 3][i % 4]"
```

or some other valid name for accessing the ith location in an array defined as:

```
int x[3][4];
```

Context: I'm writing a C program which generates C programs which filter large amounts of data based on user-defined data types and rules written in an IDL.

Edit: A python function which returns a tuple containing the location / coordinates in the array might get me going in the right direction. In particular the following array should have each element correspond with it's flat position in the array (using pylab here):

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5]],

   [[ 6,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 11]],

   [[12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]]])

In [15]: x.flat.copy()
Out[15]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
```

Comment: How would you calculate the location by hand?

Comment: @Oli That's part of what I'm asking - what is the mathematical formula for the **kth** index of an **n**-dimensional array in terms of the flat index **i** and the size of each dimension (in **int *dim**)?

Comment: I know it involves modular arithmetic and division, but I'm somewhat stumped when I try to extend it to 3 or more dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approach to solve a problem like this one is to try out a few examples. Consider the following picture that shows the memory layout for a 3D array `x[2][3][5]`:

[image: description]

How can we convert offset 14 to position `x[0][2][4]`? Well, first, we see that each `x[i]` holds 15 (3*5) blocks, so first of all we determine to which block does 14 belong to, by computing the integer division 14/15 = 0. So, offset 14 is somewhere inside `x[0]`.

We can now apply the same method. `x[i][j]` holds 5 blocks, so offset 14 belongs to block number 14/5 = 2. In fact, the correct calculation is (14/5)%3, as we will see for offset 18. And finally, `x[i][j][k]` holds single blocks, so the last index is given by 14%5. Think of it like this: we are interpreting these blocks of memory as if they had different sizes at each step. First, we assume everything is divided in chunks of 15 elements. Then, we assume everything is divided in chunks of 5 elements.

You can play with this example and see that offset 18 maps to `x[1][0][3]` because 18/15 = 1; (18/5)%3 = 0, and 18%5 = 3.

It can be seen that the general case is that for dimension `n`, we interpret the memory layout as if it was organized in `j` blocks, where `j` is the product of every dimension greater than `n`, so we have to index position `(i/j)%n`.

Here's my implementation:

```
void populateName(char *name, const char *n, int *dim, int ndim, const char *i) {
  strcpy(name, n);
  char *loc = (char*)(name + strlen(n));
  int j;
  int *mul = malloc(sizeof(int)*ndim);
  mul[ndim-1] = 1;
  /* Compute cumulative multipliers array */
  for (j = ndim-2; j >= 0; j--) {
    mul[j] = mul[j+1] * dim[j+1];
  } 
  for (j = 0; j < ndim; j++) {
    loc += sprintf(loc, "[(%s/%d)%%%d]", i, mul[j], dim[j]);
  }
  free(mul);
}
```

As you can see, it uses a cumulative array of multipliers, where `mul[i]` holds the product of every dimension greater than `i`.

By the way, you don't need `curr`; since `sprintf` returns the number of characters printed, we just have to move `loc` that same amount. It gets a little more efficient than calling `strlen` repeatedly after `sprintf`.

I don't have much time to test this, but with the example I showed, I get this:

`x[(i/15)%2][(i/5)%3][(i/1)%5]`

Which looks correct. Here's an example program:

```
int main()
{
    int dims[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    char name[1024];
    populateName(name, "x", dims, 5, "i");
    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

`x[(i/945)%2][(i/315)%3][(i/63)%5][(i/9)%7][(i/1)%9]`

It gets trickier to read for arbitrary n dimensional arrays, but the principle is always the same.

Comment: Thanks! Small fix (since the name of my iteration variable can change) would be to use `loc += sprintf(loc, "[(%s/%d)%%%d]", i, mul[j], dim[j]);` in the second for loop.